# Discord bot with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The context is that I want to make a discord bot with **discord.py** and when reading its **documentation**, it says that I can put **attributes to the classes**, but I don't know where to put them.
`class discord.ext.commands.Command(func, **kwargs)`
`@discord.ext.commands.command(name=..., cls=..., **attrs)`

If I put *!test_1 hello world* it returns only *hello*, but if I put *!test_1 "hello world"* it returns *hello world*.
the !test_2 command makes it so that there is no need to use quotes so *!test_2 this is an example* returns *this is an example*.

According to the documentation, with the rest_is_raw attribute I can make test_2 behave like test_1 and take only the first argument.

So **my problem** is that I don't know where to place the attribute.

My code:
`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!', intents=discord.Intents.all())



# Example command 1
@bot.command()
async def test_1(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

# Example command 2
@bot.command()
async def test_2(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

#Ping-pong
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="!help"))
    print('My bot is ready')

bot.run('mytokenissecret')
```

`

I tried to understand the documentation, and I put the attribute where I thought it would work, but no attempt worked.
I searched for videos but none answered my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says to put it in here :
`@bot.command(rest_is_raw=True)`

I'll add some info I got from testing.
It is possible to take a few parameters like normal, then put the rest of the message in a single parameter.

Let's say I have this command :

```py
@bot.command(rest_is_raw=True)
async def read_file(self, ctx, folder: str = "", *, file: str) :
    print(folder)
    print(file)
```

Then, with the discord message "!read_file folder name with spaces.txt", I'll get :

```
folder
 name with spaces.txt
```

Just remember to strip your raw rest :)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation really helps you to find out what's argument used for your command. In your case `test_1(ctx, arg)` and `test_2(ctx, *, arg)` are completely different. Because, in `test_2` you passing whatever you type and send in Discord. Using `*` make you passing all argument. Normally if there's no `*`, 1 argument only can accept 1 word. By using `*`, it can accept all of the words/sentence that you send in

Comment: In the documentation it talks about Parameters and gives an example of a command that takes 1 argument, and another that takes several arguments. But then he says the following:

""By default, the keyword-only arguments are stripped of white space to make it easier to work with. This behavior can be toggled by the Command.rest_is_raw argument in the decorator"".

I understood what you explained to me, my question is where do I place the Command.rest_is_raw attribute to make the command that takes several arguments work as if it only took one.